# android - aligning siblings of different relative layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I was wondering if it's possible to align 2 siblings of different relative layouts with each other.
for instance, given this XML:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  ..
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout1" >
    ..
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1 />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout2" >
    ..
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text2 />
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to align text1 and text2 with each other. is it possible? or alternately, is there some other way to achieve something like this?
thanks!!

Comment: `I would like to align text1 and text2 with each other. is it possible?` **NO**. `alternately, is there some other way to achieve something like this?` **YES**: Align both TextViews to the parent's left and their parents to the grandparent's left. Better if both TextViews were in the same container.

Comment: ok great, thanks. I had a feeling it would be a problem, but just wanted to make sure. you're welcome to write down your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: OK, done. Maybe it helps some one else too! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I would like to align text1 and text2 with each other. is it possible?`
Simply said, **NO**, it's not.
Because the controls are in different ("parallel") containers, so they aren't visible to each other.

`alternately, is there some other way to achieve something like this?`
Luckily, **YES** there is:

Align both TextViews to the parent's left and their parents to the grandparent's left.

Although, it would have been better if both TextViews were in the same container.